# input field prefilled with vuejs and a reactive character count

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As a vuejs component, I want to be able to display a character counter next to my input field.
The field is initially set up using a prop (this.initialValue).

When the method this.updateCounter is called the input textfield is blocked : typing into the field won't update its value. If I don't set the maxlength prop, the field is working fine : I can update the textfield.

Usage in a template :

```
<textfield maxlength="50" name="title" initialValue="Test"></textfield>
```

Here is the component code :

```
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <div class="input__field">
      <span class="input__limit f--small">{{ counter }}</span>
      <input type="text" :name="name" :maxlength="computedMaxlength" v-model="currentValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Textfield',
    props: {
      name: {
        default: ''
      },
      maxlength: {
        default: 0
      },
      initialValue: {
        default: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      hasMaxlength: function () {
        return this.maxlength > 0;
      },
      computedMaxlength: function () {
        if(this.hasMaxlength) return this.maxlength;
        else return false;
      },
      currentValue: {
        get: function() {
          return this.initialValue;
        },
        set: function(newValue) {
          this.updateCounter(newValue);
          this.$emit("change", newValue);
        }
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        counter: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateCounter: function (newValue) {
        if(this.maxlength > 0) this.counter = this.maxlength - newValue.length;
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {
      this.updateCounter(this.initialValue);
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Edit**

I have fixed my issue by not using v-model but instead using a value and an input event.

```
data: function () {
      return {
        value: this.initialValue,
        counter: 0
      }
},
methods: {
      updateCounter: function (newValue) {
        if(this.maxlength > 0) this.counter = this.maxlength - newValue.toString().length;
      },
      onInput: function(event) {
        const newValue = event.target.value;

        this.value = newValue;
        this.updateCounter(newValue);

        this.$emit("change", newValue);
      }
},
```

Comment: Why are you doing maxlength?

Comment: I am having a maxlength to specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the <input>. (Like in every regular forms)

Comment: Is maxlength getting set or is it 0? Maybe the default should be a realistic input number. computedMaxLength should also return a reasonable value instead of false.

Comment: To explain my issue in simpler terms :

**When this.counter is getting updated, the value of the input is getting reset to this.initialValue**.
What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Where are you updating the value at? The only thing your setter is doing is updating the counter and emitting a 'change' event that doesn't appear to be handled. So the getter just continues to return this.initialValue.

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by not using v-model. 

Instead I am using the value attribute and an input event.
So in the template I have this now : `:value="value" @input="onInput"` where value is first initiated within the data of the component. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, it makes a lot more sense to do the separation there. I never use computed setters personally.